# Indexing a vector function, $E(s)=(E_1(s),E_2(s),E_3(s))$, in MATLAB without evaulating the function

Tags: matlab

This is simple, but for some reason I can't find the solution anywhere on the internet.
I have a vector function in MATLAB
$$E(s)=(E_1(s),E_2(s),E_3(s))$$
I want to be able to index it, so normally in MATLAB you would use 'E(1)', for element one. However this just evaluates the vector at $s=2$. 'E(s)(1)' gives an error, this must be simple, it's ridiculous this is causing a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, [here's my code for reference](http://pastebin.com/vCuxkchN)

Comment: reference code link is dead

Comment: @user1772257: It's not.
http://pastebin.com/vCuxkchN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have a symbolic function that returns a vector. Type `whos` and you'll see that the class of `E` is [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html). Unfortunately, I don't think that you can directly index into a symbolic function. However, you can convert it into a symbolic expression (class `sym`) simply by setting it equal to another variable and passing in your symbolic variable `s`

```
Es = E(s);
```

Now you should be able to evaluate `Es(1)`, `Es(2)`, and `Es(3)` as you wanted.

In the future, this sort of question would probably be better suited for [Stackoverflow Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).